# Read Nested List from Database with relation and Create another List using Scala Recursivly

Tags: scala

![enter image description here][1]I have class as it is defined bellow and I read the database  fill the records with
TbMenu  List of TbMenu will be generated.

TbMenu is having its Children list pointing to Parent Id

case class TbMenu(Name:String,Url:String,Children:List[TbMenu])  - Squeryl Database case class

I want to write method to Read above structure recursively and create another list of of object  according to following structure

case class MenuBO(Name:String,Url:String,Children:List[TbMenuBO])

It will be really great help to give me some sample implementation of above.

def GenerateMenuData( orgData: List[TbMenu]): List[MenuBO] = 
{ val list: List[MenuBO] = Nil def helper(orgData:List[TbMenu], result:List[MenuBO]): List[MenuBO] = { orgData match{ case x :: tail => { val Menu = new MenuBO(x.id, x.Description, x.ParentId, x.Url, x.haschildren, null) x.children.toList match{ case x:: tail =>{ val Menu2 = new MenuBO(x.id, x.Description, x.ParentId, x.Url, x.haschildren, null) helper(tail, result ::: List(Menu2)) } case Nil => return result} Menu.Children=result helper(tail, result ::: List(Menu)) }case Nil => result }} helper(orgData,list) }

Thank you in advance

Comment: What is TbMenuBO? Was it intended to be MenuBO?

Comment: TbMenuBO is a Business object  that is used to draw menu in UI layer with play framework after filling it from TbMenu at the service layer

Comment: What's the difference between TbMenuBO and MenuBO?

Comment: TbMenu used to retrive data from Squeryl Database it has self relation  defined to it self like parent child relation ship

Comment: My question was about TbMenuBO, a list of which you are storing in class MenuBO.

Comment: I get List of Tbmenu when i read from the database inside each TBMenu it will have another list of related TBMenu as a Properpety calles Children I want to copy all TBMenu list Recursively list of TbMenuBO                                                                 thnks you

Comment: How about my solution underneath?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that TbMenuBO is the same as MenuBO, the solution can be the following:

```
def Read(menu: TbMenu): MenuBO = {
  menu match {
    case TbMenu(name, url, children) => MenuBO(name, url, children.map(Read))
  }
}
```

I suggest you adhering to the official coding conventions (method names and field names should start with lower case characters).

Comment: I tried this but not successful it works for flat list not for nested list

Comment: @BimalKaluarachchi Can you please update your question with what you tried?